# Convert row values into columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data table that looks like this, resulting from a questionnaire about what drugs (encoded as a Drug ID) people are taking:

```
ID  Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Drug4
1   45    NA    NA    NA
2   NA    NA    NA    NA
3   23    45    NA    NA
4   23    NA    NA    NA
5   57    45    23    NA
```

In other words, the 1st person is taking a drug with ID "45"  The second person is not taking any drugs.  The third person is taking drug 23 and 45.

I would like to convert this into the following matrix:

```
ID  23     45      57
1   FALSE  TRUE    FALSE
2   FALSE  FALSE    FALSE
3   TRUE   TRUE    FALSE
4   TRUE   FALSE    FALSE
5   TRUE   TRUE    TRUE
```

How can I do this in R?  I could not find a solution online that works for multiple columns like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No packages needed:

```
with( cbind(dat[1], stack(dat[-1]) ), table(ID, values) > 0 )

#   values
#ID     23    45    57
#  1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#  4  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `recast` from `reshape2` to melt then cast the data frame. The exclamation points `!!` are short for `as.logical`:

```
library(reshape2)
r <- recast(df, id.var="ID", ID~value)
cbind(r[1], !!r[,-c(1,ncol(r))])
#   ID    23    45    57
# 1  1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3  3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 4  4  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 5  5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you!  However, I get the following message: Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length.  Warning Message: Attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped

Comment: That's the function giving you information on what it did. Not a problem. You can add `value.var="value"`, but what it is saying is that it chose the column for you.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
res <- cbind(df1[1],!!mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1]))))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#  ID    23    45    57
#1  1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#2  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3  3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#4  4  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#5  5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```